# Setting/Computing Normals issue

Tags: 3d, openscenegraph

First of all I am new to modeling so forgive me if I am making any mistakes. I a using Open Scene Graph to create/view my models.

I am creating a plugin in OSG for a proprietary 3d model format that we use at my work. These model files only contain grid points and unsorted primitives such as TRI's and QUADs.

Currently when I create the model I am not setting normals since non are provided by the file format. So I used the smoothing visitor to calculate the normals for me. However when I do this I get weird white spots all over model when I rotate it and look at it.

It seems like this really occurs when there is a 2d shape that is outjutting into 3d space. (Essentially has no or almost no width).

Is there any way I can calculate the proper normals, even though they are not given? Or is there any way to fix this rendering issue.

And do not worry about the models color, each section has its own section to denote different things for our clients.

Thank you!

Cheers,
Daniel

[image: OSG 1]

[image: OSG 2]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change the crease angle to a lower value.

http://public.vrac.iastate.edu/vancegroup/docs/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs-3.0/a00737.html

Use setCreaseAngle() http://public.vrac.iastate.edu/vancegroup/docs/OpenSceneGraphReferenceDocs-3.0/a00737.html#aea511e027d0ed03728bcf75a7c56085d

to change the crease angle to something lower like 30 degrees (not you'll have to convert to radians for this call).